# customer grid not showing list when added new customer using API

Tags: magento2, customer-grid

i have created magento API to create the new user.it's functioning correctly.But newly added customer by API is showing in customer backend grid only if i **reindex** **the customer grid** .every i can't do this.anybody have solution please help with this

Comment: Did you get the solution..

Comment: Yes..i got the soultion.we can reindex customer grid through programatically.added that code

Comment: Do you know why Magento doesn't support on fly..